# Google Visualization API - Geomap regions for Germany

Tags: javascript, visualization, google-visualization, geomap

After the release of new geomap package version I seem to have a
problem using geomap for German regions. Before the upgrade everything
seemed to work just fine. The problem is that if I try to show both
the region DE-BE (Berlin) & DE-BB (Brandenburg) - the Berlin region is
not shown. If I delete the region DE-BB, or substitute it with any
other German region, for example, DE-BY (Bayern) it works fine!

Please find below test code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['geomap']});

function drawVisualization() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addRows(2);
      data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
      data.setValue(0, 0, 'DE-BE');
      data.setValue(0, 1, 200);
      data.setValue(1, 0, 'DE-BB');
      data.setValue(1, 1, 300);

      var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoMap(document.getElementById('visualization'));

      var options = {};
      options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
      options['region'] = 'DE';

      geochart.draw(data, options);
    }

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Could you please provide me with any support or ideas what might have
gone wrong?
Is it possible to include the old version of geomap package for
testing?

Answer (score 4):

Use the resolution option parameter

```
options['resolution'] = 'provinces';
```

Also the api now has a new GeoChart format which gives you even more customization such as changing the background color to match your website theme.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into jvector map. It has an SVG map of Germany and is super easy to implement. I had a lot of issues with geomap especially in old versions of the IE.

http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/

Comment: Also forgot to mention the same issue will arrise in full world view with south africa and lesotho in geomap